# Find out the user's wallpaper?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, wallpaper

Is there a way to find out what the phone's wallpaper is, and putting this wallpaper into the app?

Comment: not xcode-related. check for the usage of the tag [xcode]: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iPhone/iPad/iPod touch is jailbroken, yes. Otherwise no.

File an enhancement request if you feel this is necessary

[Apple Bug Reporter / Enhancement Request](http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/)

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not with the public iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to find out using documented SDK methods.